Is a Toeplitz operator just a multiplication operator with a bounded function on the unit disk?
I have been recently studying Hardy spaces on the unit disk (most specifically, $H^2$) and I have come across the so-called Toeplitz operators.
In every book I have found about the topic they define a Toeplitz operator as follows:

Identify $H^2$ with a subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle (I believe this is because the radial limit exists and is square integrable).

Take some $\phi \in L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$, that is, a bounded function on the unit circle.

Multiply $\phi$ with the desired function in $H^2\subset L^2(\mathbb{T})$.

Finally, do the projection from $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ to $H^2$.


Now, I do not understand why this is the case. More concretely, my questions are:
1. Isn't this the same as taking a function in $H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ and doing the product with a function directly in $H^2$? If not, why?
2. If it is indeed the same, why define it that way?

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629525

I had read this before posting and it did not help with my particular doubt.

How about $\phi(e^{it})=e^{-it}$? If I done right the Toeplitz operator is then $T(f)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}e^{int}$ for $f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}e^{int}$, that is $T(f)(0)=f'(0)$. This operator can't be generated by $f\mapsto \phi f$ for some $\phi \in H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$.

If $\phi\in L^\infty \setminus H^\infty,$ then $\phi\cdot 1\notin H^2.$

From what I gather from your question. You are asking whether the action $P(\phi f)$, where $\phi \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$, $f \in H^{2}$ is the same as the action $\psi f$, where $\psi \in H^{\infty}$. My answer to you is that its not. The classical Toeplitz operator on $H^{2}$ is defined to be the compression of the multiplication operator by a bounded function ($L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$) from $L^{2}(\mathbb{T})$ to $H^{2}$. Symbolically,
$$T_{\phi}f = P(\phi f),\;\;\;f \in H^{2}$$.
You can easily check that the matrix representation of $T_{\phi}$ is a Toeplitz matrix, that is , a matrix which is constant along the diagonals parallel to the main diagonal.
The Toeplitz operator $T_{\psi}$ with $\psi \in H^{\infty}$ becomes just a multiplication operator by the function $\psi$ since $H^{\infty}(H^{2})\subset H^{2}$ and thus the Riesz projection is just the identity operator. More explicitly,
$$T_{\psi}f = P(\psi f)= \psi f,\;\;\; f \in H^{2}. $$
However, you can check the matrix representation of $T_{\psi}$ is a lower triangular Toeplitz matrix. I believe this should be a good enough observation that $T_{\phi}$ and $T_{\psi}$ are not the same operators.
